# How to implement a simple JSON parser in c++ (can't use external libs)

Tags: c++, json, parsing

One of my clients wants to implement a JSON parser and reader in c++. 
He doesn't want to adopt a third-party library. 
So I would like to know where I can find a simple implementation of a JSON parser so I could adjust it or implement it in c++

Answer (score 0):

[Parsing JSON is a Minefield](http://seriot.ch/parsing_json.php). There are lot of different Json parsers with lot of different errors. The a summary table of errors with a list of parsers can be found  [here](http://seriot.ch/json/parsing.html) When I wrote my Json parser, there were two tricky points: Unicode support and correct support for floating point numbers. Par example, the Json specification does not limit the precision of numbers, so the following number is correct: 112345678911234567891123456789.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123
but it cannot be converted into double float number without loss of precision.
Therefore, if you are writing your own parser, you should first discuss the limitations of the parser and the results of its work.